# update location in the server while app in background

Tags: flutter, dart, location, background-process

I want to use timer to send the location update to server every x minute while app in background
is there any way in flutter to do that?

Answer (score 0):

yes and no. google will prevent you to do that because of "privacy and policy rules", here take a look https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.
and yes you can, but it will be a battery drainer application. Unless your application is a black market application which doesn't have to follow google rules I guess..

Comment: another walk around is to send a location with a fixed frequency, while your app is still on the foreground / opened.

Comment: it is a ride sharing  app and we have to track the driver location frequently even if the app in background . but I'm asking about the best way to do this and you know there are many apps contain this feature. I saw many articles but still not clear how send request to server in background,

Comment: yes they do, like gojek, grab, uber, etc. I think they use gps while the app still running on the background (not completely closed) if they are closed, then the app will tell the server to send push notification and when the user click on the push notification it will open the app and push the current location to server.

Comment: I think there should be a way to do this I will check again, thank you for your help bro

Comment: @flutter_dev_89 hello, did you found a way to do that ?